# Use "declaration" to let the readers feel that this sentence is ironic and humourous?

Tags: meaning-in-context, meaning

I think [this author uses *declaration*](http://www.theguardian.com/books/2009/aug/01/david-mitchell-short-story-rat) to let the readers feel that this sentence has irony and humour，Am I right? Because the general usage would be "but after I had heard what Lorna said, […]."

Here is the quote:

> "I have a 10 o'clock meeting with Patrick Beeman. To discuss what needs to be done." I suppose I nodded. Freddy wanted me to do my Flesh-Eating Zombie thing, but after **Lorna's declaration**, it was beyond me. She said something else that I heard but didn't really hear, climbed into the car and drove off.

Comment: I think not. He uses it to characterize what Lorna says as ominously formal, like a Declaration of Independence or a Declaration of War. Ironic, possibly, but not humorous.

Comment: It could just be that the author wanted something less wordy than "after I heard what Lorna said." I think I've seen the word _announcement_ used in a similar way, referring to a general statement, rather than a formal announcement.

Comment: still , I think that's about irony  , and about humour too, because the narrator in a bad situation can still say something like this . Thank you both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps in the context of the whole it comes across ironic. (It does to me too, but only just - because of the "Flesh-Eating Zombie thing".)  However, the phrase "Lorna's declaration" in itself is just a statement.